# CSS grid-column and row not applying to all children

Tags: html, css

As seen in my code below, I am creating a grid full of buttons for a calculator. Buttons with the class 'numkey' adhere to the grid-column and grid-row css that they are given, however both buttons with 'bluekey' and 'redkey' do not adhere to these properties when given in the exact same context. Why is this the case, and how do I get the buttons that do not respond to these parameters to respond?

```css
:root {
--pageBg1: hsl(222, 26%, 31%);
--keypadBg1: hsl(223, 31%, 20%);
--screenBg1: hsl(224, 36%, 15%);
--blueKeyBg1: hsl(225, 21%, 49%);
--blueKeyShadow1: hsl(224, 28%, 35%);
--redKeyBg1: hsl(6, 63%, 50%);
--redKeyShadow1: hsl(6, 70%, 34%);
--numberKeyBg1: hsl(30, 25%, 89%);
--numberKeyShadow1: hsl(28, 16%, 65%);
--textNumberKey1: hsl(221, 14%, 31%);
--textOther1: hsl(0, 0, 100%);
}
.keypad {
background-color: var(--keypadBg1);
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 50vh;
}
#grid {
  padding: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}


/* number key styling */

.numkey {
  background-color: var(--numberKeyShadow1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.numkey>button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--textNumberKey1);
  background-color: var(--numberKeyBg1);
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.numkey>button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.numkey:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.numkey:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.numkey:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.numkey:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.numkey:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.numkey:nth-child(6) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.numkey:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.numkey:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.numkey:nth-child(9) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.numkey:nth-child(10) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.numkey:nth-child(11) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.numkey:nth-child(12) {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.numkey:nth-child(13) {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.numkey:nth-child(14) {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.numkey:nth-child(15) {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}


/* bluekey styling */

.bluekey {
  background-color: var(--blueKeyShadow1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bluekey>button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--blueKeyBg1);
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.bluekey>button:hover {
  background-color: hsl(225, 29%, 74%);
  ;
}

.bluekey:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 4/5;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.bluekey:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}


/* redkey styling */

.redkey {
  background-color: var(--redKeyShadow1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.redkey>button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--redKeyBg1);
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.redkey:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 3/5;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
```

```html
<div class="keypad">
  <section id="grid">
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>7</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>8</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>9</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>0</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>/</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="numkey">
      <button>+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bluekey">
      <button>DEL</button>
    </div>
    <div class="bluekey">
      <button>RESET</button>
    </div>
    <div class="redkey">
      <button>=</button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: where do you want the blue and red button to show?

Comment: equal button bottom right, from column 3/5. I want the reset blue button to be bottom left, from column 1/3. del is in the right place by accident

Comment: right now, neither of the blue or red buttons respond to the class:nth-child() code

Comment: I added `n` like `.redkey:nth-child(1n) {grid-column: 4/5; grid-row: 5/6;}`. What is `n`? you can find information [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

Comment: why does this work compared to what I did?

Comment: I don't know how css grid system works. I tried to understand using you example. You have total 18 elements and `=` is 18th element. If I write `.redkey:nth-child(18) {grid-column: 4/5; grid-row: 5/6;}` It will change its position. And how it worked with `.redkey:nth-child(1n) {grid-column: 4/5; grid-row: 5/6;}` is because `n` is something like loop. [Example](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/). When `1x18`, the `=` changed its position. But still I dont know why it worked like this but not having issue with `.numkey`

Comment: I also have no clue at all

Answer (score 0):

replace this section of CSS

```
.keypad {
background-color: var(--keypadBg1);
margin-top: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
height: auto;
}

#grid {
  padding: 15px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}
```